# How to recover the original text/find decryption function?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications
[image]

Here's my book section on shift ciphers.
[image]

I understand the idea behind this. If you were trying to encrypt say a single letter 'b' with a shift cipher of key 8, you would do it by first representing 'b' as an integer, 1 because it is 1 away from 'a', and then applying the encryption formula(shift cipher) 
f(p) = (p + 8) mod 26 $\quad$= (1 + 8) mod 26  = 9.

Once you have the number 9, you revert that back to letter form, which in this case is 9 away from 'a' or 'j'.
In this problem you aren't given the key cipher though. How would you go about finding the shift cipher key?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of clues from English.  One is the [letter frequencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency#Relative_frequencies_of_letters_in_the_English_language).  In normal English text, the most common letters are ETAIONS, so count the frequencies of the encrypted letters and try to fit it to this.  For a short piece of text like this, the deviations can be large.  Another is short words.  A single letter word is likely A or I.  In three letter words, THE is very common.  In your text JVVU is very interesting.  Most words of this pattern have EE in the middle.  Also note that V ends three other words.  It is a very good bet that V encrypts E, so the shift is 17.  Seeing KYRK and KYV makes me think THAT and THE and a shift of 17 makes H to to Y.

Of course, with a shift cypher there are only 26 keys, so you could brute force it.